# How is CountDownLatch used in Java Multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, countdown, countdownlatch

Can someone help me to understand what Java `CountDownLatch` is and when to use it?

I don't have a very clear idea of how this program works. As I understand all three threads start at once and each Thread will call CountDownLatch after 3000ms. So count down will decrement one by one. After latch becomes zero the program prints "Completed". Maybe the way I understood is incorrect.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class Processor implements Runnable {
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public Processor(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

// -----------------------------------------------------

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3); // coundown from 3 to 0

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3); // 3 Threads in pool

        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Processor(latch)); // ref to latch. each time call new Processes latch will count down by 1
        }

        try {
            latch.await();  // wait until latch counted down to 0
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed.");
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: I just used your question sample code for an android parallel service batch and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Got here from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H-Vfu1v_2g) from 2012, which shows _remarkable resemblance_ to the example shown here.
For anyone interested, this is part of a Java multi-threading tutorial series from a guy named John. I like John. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Yes, you understood correctly. 
`CountDownLatch` works in latch principle, the main thread will wait until the gate is open. One thread waits for *n* threads, specified while creating the `CountDownLatch`.

Any thread, usually the main thread of the application, which calls `CountDownLatch.await()` will wait until count reaches zero or it's interrupted by another thread. All other threads are required to count down by calling `CountDownLatch.countDown()` once they are completed or ready.

As soon as count reaches zero, the waiting thread continues. One of the disadvantages/advantages of `CountDownLatch` is that it's not reusable: once count reaches zero you cannot use `CountDownLatch` any more.

**Edit:**

Use `CountDownLatch` when one thread (like the main thread) requires to wait for one or more threads to complete, before it can continue processing.

A classical example of using `CountDownLatch` in Java  is a server side core Java application which uses services architecture, where multiple services are provided by multiple threads and the application cannot start processing  until all services have started successfully.

P.S.
OP's question has a pretty straightforward example so I didn't include one.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Could you give me an example where to apply CountDown latch ?

Comment: a tutorial of how to use CountDownLatch is here http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/18/when-to-use-countdownlatch-java-concurrency-example-tutorial/

Comment: @NikolaB But in this given example we can achieve same result by using join method isn't it ?

Comment: I would consider the non-reusability an advantage: you're sure that no one can reset it, or increase the count.

Comment: @Spiderman if i use the same mechanism but instead of using threads i make the main application wait for services to complete in android,will it work the same way?

Comment: Wrt your point: *One thread waits for n number of threads specified while creating CountDownLatch in Java.* Do you mean ordering as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915135/synchronizers-are-latch-barrier-used-for-ordering)?

Comment: Nice explanation. But I would slightly disagree on the point `One thread waits for n number of threads specified while creating CountDownLatch in Java`. If you need such mechanism, then it is prudent to use `CyclicBarrier`. The fundamental conceptual difference between these two, as given in `Java concurrency in Practice` is: `Latches are for waiting for events; barriers are for waiting for other threads`. `cyclicBarrier.await()` goes into a blocking state.

Comment: From the book: `Threads call await when they reach the barrier point, and await blocks until all the threads have reached the barrier point`. Whereas in `CountdownLatch`, a single thread can generate `n` numbers of events to open the latch. Check this link: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/countdownlatch.html

Comment: do we use the `new CountDownLatch(3)` as we have 3 threads from the `newFixedThreadPool ` defined?

Comment: I think we can reuse it by writing a method which getCount and check to init it again

Answer (score 44):

`CountDownLatch` in Java is a type of synchronizer which allows one `Thread`  to wait for one or more `Thread`s before it starts processing.

`CountDownLatch` works on latch principle, thread will wait until gate is open. One thread waits for `n` number of threads specified while creating `CountDownLatch`.

e.g. `final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);`

Here we set the counter to 3.

Any thread, usually main thread of application,  which calls `CountDownLatch.await()` will wait until count reaches zero or it's interrupted by another `Thread`. All other threads are required to do count down by calling `CountDownLatch.countDown()` once they are completed or ready to the job. as soon as count reaches zero, the `Thread` awaiting starts running.

Here the count is get decremented by `CountDownLatch.countDown()` method.

The `Thread` which calls the `await()` method will wait until the initial count reaches to zero.

To make count zero other threads need to call the `countDown()` method.
Once the count become zero the thread which invoked the `await()` method will resume (start its execution).

The disadvantage of `CountDownLatch` is that it's not reusable: once the count become zero it is no longer usable.

Comment: do we use the `new CountDownLatch(3)` as we have 3 threads from the `newFixedThreadPool ` defined?

Comment: shouldn't "before it starts processing" be "before it continues processing"?

Comment: @Arefe Yes, it is number of threads going through your block of code

Answer (score 27):

It is used when we want to wait for more than one thread to complete its task. It is similar to join in threads.

**Where we can use CountDownLatch**

Consider a scenario where we have requirement where we have three threads "A", "B" and "C" and we want to start thread "C" only when "A" and "B" threads completes or partially completes their task.

**It can be applied to real world IT scenario**

Consider a scenario where manager divided modules between development teams (A and B) and he wants to assign it to QA team for testing only when both the teams completes their task.

```
public class Manager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        MyDevTeam teamDevA = new MyDevTeam(countDownLatch, "devA");
        MyDevTeam teamDevB = new MyDevTeam(countDownLatch, "devB");
        teamDevA.start();
        teamDevB.start();
        countDownLatch.await();
        MyQATeam qa = new MyQATeam();
        qa.start();
    }   
}

class MyDevTeam extends Thread {   
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
    public MyDevTeam (CountDownLatch countDownLatch, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;       
    }   
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Task assigned to development team " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Task finished by development team " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        this.countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}

class MyQATeam extends Thread {   
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Task assigned to QA team");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Task finished by QA team");
    }
}
```

**Output of above code will be:**

Task assigned to development team devB

Task assigned to development team devA

Task finished by development team devB

Task finished by development team devA

Task assigned to QA team

Task finished by QA team

Here **await()** method waits for countdownlatch flag to become 0, and **countDown()** method decrements countdownlatch flag by 1.

**Limitation of JOIN:**
Above example can also be achieved with JOIN, but JOIN can not be used in two scenarios:

1. When we use ExecutorService instead of Thread class to create threads.
2. Modify above example where Manager wants to handover code to QA team as soon as Development completes their 80% task. It means that CountDownLatch allow us to modify implementation which can be used to wait for another thread for their partial execution.

Answer (score 25):

NikolaB explained it very well, However example would be helpful to understand, So here is one simple example...

```
 import java.util.concurrent.*;


  public class CountDownLatchExample {

  public static class ProcessThread implements Runnable {

    CountDownLatch latch;
    long workDuration;
    String name;

    public ProcessThread(String name, CountDownLatch latch, long duration){
        this.name= name;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.workDuration = duration;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(name +" Processing Something for "+ workDuration/1000 + " Seconds");
            Thread.sleep(workDuration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(name+ "completed its works");
        //when task finished.. count down the latch count...

        // basically this is same as calling lock object notify(), and object here is latch
        latch.countDown();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Parent thread creating a latch object
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    new Thread(new ProcessThread("Worker1",latch, 2000)).start(); // time in millis.. 2 secs
    new Thread(new ProcessThread("Worker2",latch, 6000)).start();//6 secs
    new Thread(new ProcessThread("Worker3",latch, 4000)).start();//4 secs


    System.out.println("waiting for Children processes to complete....");
    try {
        //current thread will get notified if all chidren's are done 
        // and thread will resume from wait() mode.
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("All Process Completed....");

    System.out.println("Parent Thread Resuming work....");



     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

CoundDownLatch enables you to make a thread wait till all other threads are done with their execution.

Pseudo code can be:

```
// Main thread starts
// Create CountDownLatch for N threads
// Create and start N threads
// Main thread waits on latch
// N threads completes there tasks are returns
// Main thread resume execution
```

Comment: You might want to move out all of your description from the code block

Comment: Best comment though. I like these "to the point" comments instead of theorical explanations.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), CountDownLatch is a synchronization aid, introduced in Java 5. Here the synchronization does not mean restricting access to a critical section. But rather sequencing actions of different threads.
        The type of synchronization achieved through CountDownLatch is similar to that of Join.
        Assume that there is a thread "M" which needs to wait for other worker threads "T1", "T2", "T3" to complete its tasks 
        Prior to Java 1.5, the way this can be done is, M running the following code

```
    T1.join();
    T2.join();
    T3.join();
```

The above code makes sure that thread M resumes its work after T1, T2, T3 completes its work. T1, T2, T3 can complete their work in any order. 
    The same can be achieved through CountDownLatch, where T1,T2, T3 and thread M share same CountDownLatch object.
    "M" requests :  `countDownLatch.await();`  
    where as "T1","T2","T3" does  `countDownLatch.countdown();`

One disadvantage with the join method is that M has to know about T1, T2, T3. If there is a new worker thread T4 added later, then M has to be aware of it too. This can be avoided with CountDownLatch.
    After implementation the sequence of action would be [T1,T2,T3](the order of T1,T2,T3 could be anyway) -> [M]

Answer (score 3):

This example from [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) helped me understand the concepts clearly:

```
class Driver { // ...
  void main() throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // create and start threads
      new Thread(new Worker(startSignal, doneSignal)).start();

    doSomethingElse();            // don't let run yet
    startSignal.countDown();      // let all threads proceed
    doSomethingElse();
    doneSignal.await();           // wait for all to finish
  }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {
  private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
  private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
  Worker(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
     this.startSignal = startSignal;
     this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
  }
  public void run() {
     try {
       startSignal.await();
       doWork();
       doneSignal.countDown();
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} // return;
  }

  void doWork() { ... }
}
```

Visual interpretation:

[image]

Evidently, `CountDownLatch` allows one thread (here `Driver`) to wait until a bunch of running threads (here `Worker`) are done with their execution.

Answer (score 2):

One good example of when to use something like this is with Java Simple Serial Connector, accessing serial ports. Typically you'll write something to the port, and asyncronously, on another thread, the device will respond on a SerialPortEventListener. Typically, you'll want to pause after writing to the port to wait for the response. Handling the thread locks for this scenario manually is extremely tricky, but using Countdownlatch is easy. Before you go thinking you can do it another way, be careful about race conditions you never thought of!!

Pseudocode:

```
CountDownLatch latch;
void writeData() { 
   latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
   serialPort.writeBytes(sb.toString().getBytes())
   try {
      latch.await(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
}
class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
            byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue());
            latch.countDown();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add some debug after your call to latch.countDown(), this may help you understand its behaviour better.

```
latch.countDown();
System.out.println("DONE "+this.latch); // Add this debug
```

The output will show the Count being decremented. This 'count' is effectively the number of Runnable tasks (Processor objects) you've started against which countDown() has **not** been invoked and hence is blocked the main thread on its call to latch.await().

```
DONE java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@70e69696[Count = 2]
DONE java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@70e69696[Count = 1]
DONE java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@70e69696[Count = 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

From oracle documentation about [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

A `CountDownLatch` is initialized with a given count. The `await` methods block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the `countDown()` method, after which all waiting threads are released and any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset.

> A CountDownLatch is a versatile synchronization tool and can be used for a number of purposes.

A `CountDownLatch` initialized with a count of one serves as a simple on/off latch, or gate: all threads invoking await wait at the gate until it is opened by a thread invoking countDown().

A `CountDownLatch` initialized to N can be used to make one thread wait until N threads have completed some action, or some action has been completed N times.

```
public void await()
           throws InterruptedException
```

> Causes the current thread to wait until the latch has counted down to zero, unless the thread is interrupted.

If the current count is zero then this method returns immediately.

```
public void countDown()
```

> Decrements the count of the latch, releasing all waiting threads if the count reaches zero.

If the current count is greater than zero then it is decremented. If the new count is zero then all waiting threads are re-enabled for thread scheduling purposes.

Explanation of your example.

1. You have set count as 3 for `latch` variable

   ```
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
   ```
2. You have passed this shared `latch` to Worker thread : `Processor`
3. Three `Runnable` instances of `Processor` have been submitted to `ExecutorService` `executor`
4. Main thread ( `App` ) is waiting for count  to become zero with below statement

   ```
    latch.await();
   ```
5. `Processor` thread sleeps for 3 seconds and then it decrements count value with `latch.countDown()`
6. First `Process` instance will change latch count as 2 after it's completion due to `latch.countDown()`.
7. Second `Process` instance will change latch count as 1 after it's completion due to `latch.countDown()`.
8. Third `Process` instance will change latch count as 0 after it's completion due to `latch.countDown()`.
9. Zero count on latch causes main thread `App` to come out from `await`
10. App program prints this output now : `Completed`

Answer (score 2):

```
package practice;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class CountDownLatchExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch c= new CountDownLatch(3);  // need to decrements the count (3) to zero by calling countDown() method so that main thread will wake up after calling await() method 
        Task t = new Task(c);
        Task t1 = new Task(c);
        Task t2 = new Task(c);
        t.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        c.await(); // when count becomes zero main thread will wake up 
        System.out.println("This will print after count down latch count become zero");
    }
}

class Task extends Thread{
    CountDownLatch c;

    public Task(CountDownLatch c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            c.countDown();   // each thread decrement the count by one 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best real time Example for countDownLatch explained in this link [CountDownLatchExample](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/when-to-use-countdownlatch-java-concurrency-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is `CyclicBarrier`, as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html
See:

> A CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. The await methods block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the countDown() method, after which all waiting threads are released and any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.