# Simultaneously processing in one Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, asynchronous

I have a Servlet which recieves a request, has to process 5 tasks (Grab data Form external Servers) and send all the data back to the client ordered.

How to process the 5 Task simultaneously and continue with the servlet code after all 5 tasks are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CoundDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

sample code:

```
    CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(5); // 5 tasks

    class Worker implements Runnable {
        private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
        private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
        private final int threadNumber;

        // you can pass additional arguments as well
        Worker(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal,
                                                   int threadNumber) {
            this.startSignal = startSignal;
            this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                startSignal.await();
                doWork(); // actual work to be performed here    
                doneSignal.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.error(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // 5 new threads are started
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        new Thread(new Worker(startSignal, doneSignal, i)).start();
    }

    startSignal.countDown(); // let all threads proceed
    try {
        doneSignal.await(); // wait for all to finish
        // all 5 tasks are finished and do whatever you want to do next
    } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
        LOGGER.error(interruptedException);
    }
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827022/what-is-countdown-latch-in-java-multithreading) and [Find more examples...](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thx, thats a good solution.
But in your Example I just start the same task (here: doWork()) 5 times in 5 threads.
How to start 5 different tasks?

Comment: As in the code I have started 5 threads. just check the threadNumber in the worker class and do based on that number.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). There are a variety of examples available including the following:

- [How to wait for all threads to finish, using ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice)
- [ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish)

Here is some example code taken from the first link found above:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
while(...) {
  taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());
}
taskExecutor.shutdown();
try {
  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: have you tested it for Servlet in clustered environment?

Comment: @user3218114 Your original question doesn't mention anything about a clustered environment. This is just some sample code and references to get you started. You'll have to try it out and see if this fits your requirements.

Comment: I am not OP. I used CountDownLatch in a live application and after that I have shared it as an answer. I am just asking. No worries.

Comment: @user3218114 Right, sorry. Your username confused me. It's very similar to OP. You need a unique one lol! I've used the `ExecutorService` in a live application but it wasn't in a clustered environment. But I believe that it is widely used in Java.

Comment: yes Sid If you look at my previous edit then I suggested to use ExecutorService then I haven't tested it hence I have edited my post again.

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds is too long, it might take up the web server resource, you can let the client to send a request A, which trigger your 5 seconds task, but it don't wait, return immediately.Since you know it will take 5 seconds, you can send another request B, 5 seconds later, to get the data. If data not ready yet, you can request after another 5 seconds, until MAX_RETRY_COUNT (defined by yourself) reached.