# Test framework in Spring Amqp

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, spring-amqp

Is there any test framework around Spring Amqp , I have explored lots of areas but couldn't find one

Answer (score 0):

What, specifically, are you looking for regarding a test framework?

In user test cases, you can use many of the same techniques that the framework itself uses in [its unit and integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/tree/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit).

We **are** considering baking in some test support into the framework; see the recent discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454159/how-to-write-an-integration-test-for-rabbitlistener-annotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099160/rabbitmq-integration-test-and-threading).

You can provide specific requirements via a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Perfect , But i need some kind of a mocking framework around Spring AMQP for Unit Testing Eg. We have created a configuration class For RabbitMQ configuration and some classes producing messages and some consuming , So does Spring AMQP provides a mocking framework around it ? If Yes can you please help us on that if no can we raise a JIRA Issue .  As we follow TDD extensively so we have to mock Spring AMQP objects through Mockito but it dosn't give us perfect way of Unit testing our cases

Comment: The framework uses Mockito extensively in its test suite. However, there is currently no high-level Mockito support - all the mocking is done at a very low level - mocking the amqp-client channel, for example. We'd be happy to look at adding some higher-level support, but this is a very broad subject, so some specific examples of what you need would be helpful. "some producing and some consuming" is not really specific enough. The testing framework will evolve over time but it needs to start with something concrete.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring amqp 1.6.x, it spring amqp test is available as a separate Jar file.
Have a loo at this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/16/spring-amqp-1-6-0-milestone-1-and-1-5-4-available).