# Configure MessagePostProcessor globally in Spring RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-amqp

> Related to
>   [How do we hook into before/After message processing using @RabbitListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513662)

If I want to configure RabbitTemplate globally and set `MessagePostProcessor`, what is the best way?

1. Should I copy the bean definition from `RabbitAutoConfiguration`?
2. Or should I intercept the bean definition using `BeanPostProcessor`?

The problem with first solution is that, 
RabbitTemplate in `RabbitAutoConfiguration` is not just [bounding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.html) the properties to the bean instance but also set message converts:

```
MessageConverter messageConverter = this.messageConverter.getIfUnique();
if (messageConverter != null) {
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
}
```

So, should I duplicate this logic as follows, or just follow the second option of `BeanPostProcessor` as in [Sleuth](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/26417a27079bf353cacdfd25eed8e29b741d1893/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java#L169)?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.rabbitmq.template")
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                     ObjectProvider<MessageConverter> messageConverterObjectProvider) {

    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    MessageConverter messageConverter = messageConverterObjectProvider.getIfUnique();
    if (messageConverter != null) {
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    }
    template.setBeforePublishPostProcessors(myBeforePublishMPP());
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is just enough to `@Autowired` an auto-configured `RabbitTemplate` and inject your `MessagePostProcessor` into that `RabbitTemplate`:

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.rabbitTemplate.setBeforePublishPostProcessors(myMessagePostProcessor());
}

@Bean
public MessagePostProcessor myMessagePostProcessor() {
    return message -> null;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but I think will need to put this post-construct method in every service injecting the rabbitTemplate. (according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L207)

Comment: No, that's not. The `RabbitTemplate` is a *singleton* bean, therefore it is enough to mutate it only once. All other places will get it already with your post-processor.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the first way so the application.properties are applied, but change the method signature to receive the `ObjectProvider< MessageConverter>` like they do in Sleuth.

Comment: It is okay to duplicate the `MessageConverter` part?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use an `ObjectProvider` and `getIfUnique()`.