# Java/Corba: Send message to all users

Tags: java

I am completely new to Java/Corba, I am making a two player game.
How can I make server notify all users when specific condition is met?
For example: I have an array with [Player1, Player2] when both are not null I want all players to be notified that the game is ready. 
How can I do that? is there any simple method?

So far my only solution is: 
while game is not ready{
call function to check if both slots are filled every x seconds.
}
when it comes back and says both slots were filled - players begin game. 
I literally need this just for a small simple college project, any easy way?

Comment: Consider a CountDownLatch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827022/what-is-countdown-latch-in-java-multithreading

Comment: Have each player's JVM open a socket to the server, and have the server serialize objects over each player socket which indicate game status.