# Multiple Threads in a thread pool writing data in same List

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm having multiple threads running in my `threadPool` Each thread reads a huge file and returns the data from this file in a List.

Code looks like :

```
class Writer{


   ArrayList finalListWhereDataWillBeWritten = new Array<Integer>()
   for(query q : allQueries){ //all the read queries to read file

      threadPool.submit(new GetDataFromFile(fileName,filePath));        

   }//all the read queries have been submitted.

}
```

Now I know that following section of code will occur some where in my code but I don't know where to place it.
Because if I place it just after `submit()`  in for loop it'll not add it because each file is very huge and may not have completed its processing.

```
synchronized(finalListWhereDataWillBeWritten){

  //process the data obtained from single file and add it to target list 
      finalListWhereDataWillBeWritten.addAll(dataFromSingleThread); 

}
```

So can anyone please tell me that where do I place this chunk of code and what other things I need to make sure of so that Critical Section Problem donot occur.

```
class GetDataFromFile implements Runnable<List<Integer>>{

   private String fileName;
   private String filePath;

   public List<Integer> run(){
       //code for streaming the file fileName 
       return dataObtainedFromThisFile;
   }

}
```

And do i need to use `wait()` / `notifyAll()` methods in my code given that I'm only reading data from files parallely in threads and placing them in a shared List

Comment: This is a half baked question. Please post all relevant code before the question is closed.

Comment: What else information do you need?I can provide that

Comment: For starters, what happens between the two code fragments that you showed. What is `dataFromSingleThread`? Why don't you post the actual code snippets instead?

Comment: Code base is very huge more than 600 lines thats why...I'm posting a summary of what problem I'm facing

Comment: meanwhile I'm adding some more info

Comment: updated...now see if u need some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Please consider the answer provided by Marko which is far better

If you want to ensure that your threads all complete before you work on your list, do the following:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ThreadWork {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 5;
    Thread[] threads = new ListThread[count];
    List<String> masterList = new Vector<String>();

    for(int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
      threads[index] = new ListThread(masterList, "Thread " + (index + 1));
      threads[index].start();
    }
    while(isOperationRunning(threads)) {
      // do nothing
    }

    System.out.println("Done!! Print Your List ...");

    for(String item : masterList){
      System.out.println("[" + item + "]");
    }
  }

  private static boolean isOperationRunning(Thread[] threads) {
    boolean running = false;

    for(Thread thread : threads) {
      if(thread.isAlive()) {
        running = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return running;
  }
}

class ListThread extends Thread {
  private static String items[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
  private List<String> list;
  private String name;

  public ListThread(List<String> masterList, String threadName) {
    list = masterList;
    name = threadName;
  }

  public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length;++i) {
      randomWait();
      String data = "Thread [" + name + "][" + items[i] + "]";
      System.out.println( data );
      list.add( data );
    }
  }

  private void randomWait() {
    try {
      Thread.currentThread();
      Thread.sleep((long)(3000 * Math.random()));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException x) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Well your code is fine and will do what I want.....but don't you think that polling it continuously will increase the time of execution of this program?

Comment: The point of threads is to run processes concurrently. If I have ten files to process, I can process ten threads at once instead of one at a time. Sometimes, however,  you need to act upon the results of the Thread work only AFTER ALL the threads are complete. Again, if this was not what you want, let me know and I will delete this answer

Comment: Why you are asking to delete again and again...may be your answer can help someone in future.

Comment: My intent here is to help you

Comment: You may also consider using a synchronized list (Thread-safe master list) or a Vector to add the data to the master list within each individual Thread itself ... Just pass a reference of the master list to each Thread... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444005/how-do-i-make-my-arraylist-thread-safe-another-approach-to-problem-in-java

Comment: agreed...but how if I pass my list to the Runnable Class how can I make sure that the data I modify here in Runnable Class will be reflected there in Main Thread Class

Comment: while searching for a solution I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827022/what-is-countdown-latch-in-java-multithreading

This is another very useful approach

Comment: any suggestions on passing the reference of my list so that i can add data from there ? Actually I'm a newbie in Java

Comment: I modified the code in answer to use a referenced Vector so no need to issue an addAll as it is done immediately within each Thread. Note however that your results will no longer be sorted, ofcourse

Comment: fine..i think you should also lock....masterList as multiple threads are writing into this.

Comment: I do like the example you noted, however in a previous question. Many ways to skin a cat ...

Comment: Polling the threads via `isAlive()` will raise the CPU load and *will* increase the execution time unless you have more CPU cores than threads. There is no reason for such a polling loop. Just call `join()` once on each thread, the order doesn’t matter, and after that, you know that all threads are done.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I hope op considers accepting Marko's answer instead ...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reinventing the wheel you should simply implement `Callable<List<Integer>>` and submit it to the JDK's standard Executor Service. Then, as the futures complete, you collect the results into the list.

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
final List<Future<List<Integer>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(query q : allQueries) {
  futures.add(threadPool.submit(new GetDataFromFile(fileName, filePath)));
}
for (Future<List<Integer>> f : futures) {
    finalListWhereDataWillBeWritten.addAll(f.get());
}
```

And this is all assuming you are below Java 8. With Java 8 you would of course use a parallel stream:

```
final List<Integer> finalListWhereDataWillBeWritten =
  allQueries.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(q -> getDataFromFile(q.fileName, q.filePath))
            .collect(toList());
```