# How to pause a method java

Tags: java, methods, wait, sleep

i want method 2 to sleep until method 1 allow method 2 to continue to run again. How do I accomplish this pause?

```
method 1{
some code here
if(enter key pressed){
allow method 2 to continue
}
}
method 2{
some code here
wait until method 1 allow you to continue
do whatever you are supposed to continue with
}
```

Comment: How do these methods interact?  How have you built the threads for this task?

Answer (score 0):

In any language methods should be precise and **ONE-TASK oriented**, if method 2 begins a tasks and then waits for external calls to continue, then that is a good sign of smelly code,

I will suggest to take a look at the code an split their actions is more specific task and then bind them in the logic you need.

**LIKE**

```
method 1{
        some code here
        method2_SubTaskA()
        if(enter key pressed){
            allow method 2 to continue
            method2_SubTaskB()
        }
}
method 2SubTaskA{
        some code here
        wait until method 1 allow you to continue
        do whatever you are supposed to continue with
}
method 2SubTaskB{
        some code here
        wait until method 1 allow you to continue
        do whatever you are supposed to continue with
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multithreading for this:

```
boolean method2Continue = false;

public void method1() {
    // ...
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> method2());
    thread.start();
    if(keyPressed){
        method2Continue = true;
    }
    thread.interrupt();
    // ...
}
public void method2() {
    // ...
    while(!method2Continue);
    // ...
}
```

After `thread.start()` is called, method 1 and method 2 will execute simultaneously, but when method 2 reaches the while loop, it will wait for `method2Continue` to be true until it continues on to the next line. At the end of method 1, the method 2 thread will be terminated which will stop its execution.

See a demo here: https://ideone.com/eqnTh7

Comment: You should probably add the `volatile` keyword to  `method2Continue`

Comment: this seem to be good but i get an red line under InterruptedException in the try catch and the message
"Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameter"

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple threads can be avoided here:

```
private Runnable runnable;

void method1() {
    // Some code here
    if(enter key pressed && runnable != null) {
        runnable.run(); // Execute continue code
        runnable = null; // Make sure it can't be run twice
    }
}

void method2() {
    // Some code here
    runnable = new Runnable(() -> {
        // Continue code here
    });
}
```

Using an anonymous class will allow you to capture variables from `method2`.

Answer (score 0):

As @SamTebbs33 said, use multi threading; his example is a good starting point. Instead of using a `boolean`, I recommend using a `CountdownLatch` to indicate that it's time for `method2` to continue. A detailed example is given in the following question: [How is CountDownLatch used in Java Multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827022/what-is-countdown-latch-in-java-multithreading)

In general, using the built-in concurrency APIs is safer than writing your own home-grown solution---it is more widely understandable and less error prone.

See the `CoubtdownLatch` JavaDocs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html