# Multithreaded summation of an array without using join ()

Tags: java, multithreading

I separate the array and sum its parts separately, at the end, adding everything to a single variable using join.

class code Main

```
int partArray = array.length / THREAD;
int first = 0;
AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger(0);
Thread[] thr = new Thread[THREAD];

for(i = 0; i < THREAD; ++i) {
    thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadSum(first, first + partArray, array, result));
    thr[i].start();
    first += partArray;
}

for(i = 0; i < THREAD; ++i) {
    thr[i].join();
}
```

class code Thread

```
int first;
int end;
private int[] array;
private AtomicInteger result;

public ThreadSum(int first, int end, int[] array, AtomicInteger result) {
    this.first = first;
    this.end = end;
    this.array = array;
    this.result = result;
}

public synchronized void run() {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = first; i < end; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    result.getAndAdd(sum);
}
```

How do I implement this without using join?
Any help guys.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid join() in the first place? What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve by avoiding the use of join()?

Comment: Why is `run()` synchronized? It will never be called concurrently?

Comment: There is no way to avoid using `join()` if you want consistent results at the end. Also, `synchronized` is pointless since chunks of the array can be summed in parallel, that's the point of parallel summation.

Comment: Have a look here: [How is CountDownLatch used in Java Multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334253/2838289)

Comment: @JBNizet They just gave me the task. Make multithreaded summation of an array without using join.

Comment: OK. So this is just an exercise. Use a COuntDownLatch to achieve the equivalent. Or just use a parallel stream instead of handling threads and synchronization by yourself: `IntStream.of(array).parallel().sum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, all the answers and comments from @Tudor and @JBNizet helped me solve the problem. I used CountDownLatch.

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(THREAD);
    for(i = 0; i < THREAD; ++i) {
        thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadSum(first, first + partArray, array, result,countDownLatch));
        thr[i].start();
        first += partArray;
    }
    countDownLatch.await();
```

class code Thread

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

public ThreadSum(int first, int end, int[] array, AtomicInteger result, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
    this.first = first;
    this.end = end;
    this.array = array;
    this.result = result;
    this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println(currentThread().getName());
    for(int i = first; i < end; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    countDownLatch.countDown();
    result.getAndAdd(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is version of the code using a thread pool that *technically* fulfills the requirement of not using `join()`:

```
int partArray = array.length / THREAD;
int first = 0;
AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger(0);
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for(i = 0; i < THREAD; ++i) {
    threadPool.execute(new ThreadSum(first, first + partArray, array, result));
    first += partArray; 
}

threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

There are a couple of things not ok here:

1. Using `join()` is required because otherwise there is no precise point in the program execution where you can safely retrieve the computed sum and know that the parallel summation is finished.
2. `synchronized` on the run method is not required because individual array chunks can be summed up in parallel and you are already using `AtomicInteger` for synchronization.

Comment: They just gave me the task. Make multithreaded summation of an array without using join. And yes I know that the synchronization of the run method is meaningless. I just played in and forgot to remove it. 
However, thank you for having responded to me.

Comment: @J.doe: Ok, if that's the requirement... I will post a solution using Executors soon.

Comment: Your answer did not work, and in the end I used countDownLatch. Which ultimately helped. In the end, you helped me create the right vector for development. Thank you all! The answer can be considered closed. I will attach the answers in my question.

Comment: @J.doe: Can you specify what exactly didn't work in the code above?

Comment: awaitTermination must take a value, something like (60, TimeUnit.SECONDS). If I delete it, the threads return zero result. The call to @Tudor for some reason does not work. Sorry.

Comment: @J.doe: Ah yes, sorry about that. What you want to do is wait indefinitely for the tasks to finish. See my updated code.