# Multithreaded summation of an array without the use of join () and java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading

I already had a similar question, to which I was helped to answer. [Multithreaded summation of an array without using join ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184936/multithreaded-summation-of-an-array-without-using-join/51194427#51194427)
**It is successfully closed.** However, now the question is ***not to use*** the java.util.concurrent library. My mentor says it's possible.

I have no idea, except how to implement my own join () inside which is used wait () and isAlive ()

Comment: I hate silly homework assignments. "Don't use this obvious construct because I say so." :(

Comment: @Tudor I understand you so well. In real life, this task will never occur.

Comment: Dont know if your mentor will like this or not 
 but give a try `Arrays.asList(intArray).parallelStream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();`