# Countdownlatch get count returns inconsistent values

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch

I have developed a sample java program to understand countdownlatch & initialized the countdownlatch with count 4. I expected that after countDown method, the getCount() would return the remaining count for the countdownlatch. But, in the following example:-

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);
    Worker first = new Worker(latch, "WORKER-1");
    Worker second = new Worker(latch, "WORKER-2");
    Worker third = new Worker(latch, "WORKER-3");
    Worker fourth = new Worker(latch, "WORKER-4");
    first.start();
    second.start();
    third.start();
    fourth.start();

    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Final Count:- " + latch.getCount());
}
}


class Worker extends Thread {
private CountDownLatch latch;

public Worker(CountDownLatch latch, String name) {
    super(name);
    this.latch = latch;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    latch.countDown();
    System.out.println("Count:- " + latch.getCount());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished");
}
}
```

The output is :-

Count:- 2

Count:- 1

Count:- 2

WORKER-3 finished

WORKER-1 finished

WORKER-2 finished

Count:- 0

Final Count:- 0

WORKER-4 finished.

The count is returned as 2 for two times in the output. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem.
[How is CountDownLatch used in Java Multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827022/how-is-countdownlatch-used-in-java-multithreading)

This method only do a `volatile` read, not a `synchronised` read.

```
 /**
 * Returns the current count.
 *
 * <p>This method is typically used for debugging and testing purposes.
 *
 * @return the current count
 */
public long getCount() {
    return sync.getCount();
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with synchronised read. Even it is a synchronised read, it could also get `Count:- 2` twice. Like I said in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608472/6690200

Answer (score 0):

The four `Worker`s are running at the same time. Since `latch.countDown();` and `latch.getCount()` are not atomic, the execution order could be：

```
thread1 latch.countDown();
thread2 latch.countDown();
thread1 System.out.println("Count:- " + latch.getCount()); // Count:- 2
thread2 System.out.println("Count:- " + latch.getCount()); // Count:- 2
```