# How to use invokeAll() to let all thread pool do their task?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, executorservice, future

```
    ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
        List<Future<Hotel>> future=new ArrayList<Future<Hotel>>();
        List<Callable<Hotel>> callList = new ArrayList<Callable<Hotel>>();

        for(int i=0;i<=diff;i++){

            String str="2013-"+(liDates.get(i).get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+liDates.get(i).get(Calendar.DATE);

            callList.add(new HotelCheapestFare(str));

        }       
     future=pool.invokeAll(callList);
for(int i=0;i<=future.size();i++){

        System.out.println("name is:"+future.get(i).get().getName());
    }
```

Now I want pool to `invokeAll` all the task before getting to the for loop but when I run this program for loop gets executed before that `invokeAll` and throws this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source) at  
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at 
com.mmt.freedom.cheapestfare.TestHotel.main(TestHotel.java:6‌​5)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.mmt.freedom.cheapestfare.HotelCheapestFare.getHotelCheap‌estFare(HotelCheapes‌​tFare.java:166) 
at com.mmt.freedom.cheapestfare.HotelCheapestFare.call(HotelChe‌​apestFare.java:219)
at com.mmt.freedom.cheapestfare.HotelCheapestFare.call(HotelChe‌​apestFare.java:1) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknow‌​n Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: InvokeAll should wait till all Callables have finished. Could you please add the exception and the stack trace?

Comment: internaly some thread goes to for loop before completion and throws exception

Comment: please help me i have to submit my task

Comment: According your stack trace: `com.mmt.freedom.cheapestfare.HotelCheapestFare.getHotelCheapestFare(HotelCheapes‌​tFare.java:166)`. Error should be there.

Comment: i have a list at this point but when i debug it i am getting my list

Comment: what i thing is that some thread is accessing some other thread internally and its going to for loop before completion of pool.invoke()

Comment: You definitely must look at `HotelCheapes‌tFare.java`line 166 as @aim mentioned! It looks like you just access some object that is `null`. Nothing special about threads and tasks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way an `ExecutorService` works is that when you call `invokeAll` it waits for all tasks to complete:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each
>   element of the returned list. **Note that a completed task could have
>   terminated either normally or by throwing an exception**. The results of
>   this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while
>   this operation is in progress.<sup>[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)</sup>(emphasis added)

What that means is that your tasks are all done but some may have thrown an exception. This exception is part of the `Future` - calling `get` causes the exception to be rethrown wrapped in an `ExecutionException`.

From you stacktrack

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at 
                                ^^^ <-- from get
```

You can see that this is indeed the case. One of your tasks has failed with an NPE. The `ExecutorService` caught the exception and is telling you about it by throwing an `ExecutionException` when you call `Future.get`.

Now, if you want to take tasks *as they complete* you need an `ExecutorCompletionService`. This acts as a `BlockingQueue` that will allow you to poll for tasks as and when they finish.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    final ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                try {
                    final Future<String> myValue = completionService.take();
                    //do stuff with the Future
                    final String result = myValue.get();
                    System.out.println(result);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    System.err.println("TASK FAILED");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        completionService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("FAILED");
                }
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
        });
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

In this example I have one task that calls `take` on the `ExecutorCompletionService` which gets the `Future`s as they become available and then I submit tasks to the `ExecutorCompletionService`.

This will allow you to get the failed task as soon as it fails rather than having to wait for all the tasks to either fail of succeed together.

The only complication is that it is difficult to tell the polling thread that all the tasks are done as everything is now asynchronous. In this instance I have used the knowledge that 100 tasks will be submitted so that it only need to poll 100 times. A more general way would be to collect the `Future`s from the `submit` method as well and then loop over them to see if everything is completed.

Comment: can i use  ExecutorCompletionService<hotel> with list of callable objects

Comment: @SahilKohli No, and that makes no sense. The reason you use a `Collection` in the `ExecutorService` is so that you can wait for **all** of them to finish before proceeding. With the ` ExecutorCompletionService` you are polling for completion so it makes no difference if you submit them all at once or in a loop.

Comment: my task is time consuming so i want them to run concurrently so that they all run at the same time and i get my future result after completion of threads

Comment: In that case you can use the `invokeAll` method of the `ExecutorService` and process all the `Future`s as you are currently doing. The reason to use an `ExecutorCompletionListener` is that you are notified as soon as each task is completed. These are two different things. I don't understand what you want; you can **either** process each result as it happens **or** process everything at the end. **In either case** you need to handle possible `ExecutionException`s.

Comment: yes I want forloop to only work after the completion of invokeall() but its working just after one or two threads gets completed so kindly tell me how to prevent my for loop so that it executes only after the completion of list.

Comment: @SahilKohli **NO IT IS NOT**. It runs after **all of your tasks have completed** as stated in the Javadoc. What is happening, as I explain above, is that one of your tasks is throwing an NPE from the `call` method and you are not handling the `ExecutionException` that is thrown from `Future.get`.

Answer (score 11):

[Future.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) throws below exceptions.

`CancellationException` - if the computation was cancelled

`ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception

`InterruptedException` - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting

Catch all these exceptions when you call `get()` method.

I have simulated divide by zero exception for some `Callable` tasks but exception in one `Callable` does not affect other `Callable` tasks submitted to `ExecutorService` if you catch above three exceptions as shown in example code.

Example code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InvokeAllUsage{
    public InvokeAllUsage(){
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<MyCallable> futureList = new ArrayList<MyCallable>();
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i+1);
            futureList.add(myCallable);
        }
        System.out.println("Start");
        try{
            List<Future<Long>> futures = service.invokeAll(futureList);  
            for(Future<Long> future : futures){
                try{
                    System.out.println("future.isDone = " + future.isDone());
                    System.out.println("future: call ="+future.get());
                }
                catch (CancellationException ce) {
                    ce.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        InvokeAllUsage demo = new InvokeAllUsage();
    }
    class MyCallable implements Callable<Long>{
        Long id = 0L;
        public MyCallable(Long val){
            this.id = val;
        }
        public Long call(){

            if ( id % 5 == 0){
                id = id / 0;
            }           
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
creating service
Start
future.isDone = true
future: call =1
future.isDone = true
future: call =2
future.isDone = true
future: call =3
future.isDone = true
future: call =4
future.isDone = true
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at InvokeAllUsage.<init>(InvokeAllUsage.java:20)
        at InvokeAllUsage.main(InvokeAllUsage.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at InvokeAllUsage$MyCallable.call(InvokeAllUsage.java:47)
        at InvokeAllUsage$MyCallable.call(InvokeAllUsage.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
future.isDone = true
future: call =6
future.isDone = true
future: call =7
future.isDone = true
future: call =8
future.isDone = true
future: call =9
future.isDone = true
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at InvokeAllUsage.<init>(InvokeAllUsage.java:20)
        at InvokeAllUsage.main(InvokeAllUsage.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at InvokeAllUsage$MyCallable.call(InvokeAllUsage.java:47)
        at InvokeAllUsage$MyCallable.call(InvokeAllUsage.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Completed
```

Comment: Good explanation +1, so is it better to use service.invokeAll(futureList) or recursive with service.submit(new Runnable)? Is there any significant difference in time of execution between both method? Or is it just for different goals i.e return value?

Comment: When you need to wait for result of all tasks, use invokeAll. Otherwise you can use submit of task.

Answer (score -1):

invokeAll is a blocking method. It means – JVM won’t proceed to next line until all the threads are completed.  So I think there is something wrong with your thread future result.

```
System.out.println("name is:"+future.get(i).get().getName());
```

from this line I think there are some futures have no result and can be null, So you should check your code, if there are some Futures null,If so, get a if before this line executed.

Comment: This is so wrong. Look at the stacktrace. The `Future.get` method is throwing an `ExectuionExcetion` - that is obvious. The result **is not** `null`. The `Callable` encountered a `NullPointerException` in the `call` method. This is caught in the `Future` and then wrapped in an `ExectionException`.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException, So It is  the Future Code get this exception.

Comment: so some other better solution