# Why does ExecutorService.invokeAll() return a List of Future?

Tags: java, concurrency

`invokeAll()` doesn't return until all the `Callable`s in the submitted `Collection` have completed, so what is the reason for making the results `Future`s?

Comment: Have you seen [this informative question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202388/how-to-use-invokeall-to-let-all-thread-pool-do-their-task). Please have a look, especially Boris's answer, and let me know if this answers some of your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the task might terminate normally or exceptionally, `Futures` can wrap the exception for you. For example,

```
Callable<Integer> c1 = () -> 1;
Callable<Integer> c2 = () -> {
        throw new RuntimeException();
};

List<Future<Integer>> futures = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(c1,c2));
for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
  System.out.println(future.get());
}
```

Note that because of `Future`, we were able to get a result of the future that terminated normally and the that terminated exceptionally.

If `invokeAll` returned a `List<T>`, it would have to return those that completed successfully and discarded those with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

### Checking the [ExecutorService#invokeAll Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each
>   element of the returned list. ***Note that a completed task could have
>   terminated either normally or by throwing an exception.*** The results
>   of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while
>   this operation is in progress.

Means that we're getting a list of `Future` objects because there may be situations where we do not get a value even if the task is complete.