# Calling threads in loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a code which has following methods:

- downloadFile() - download file from ftpserver
- processFile() - read file line by line and process the line
- sendSMS() - send SMS to vendors how many records got processed.

The `processFile` method reads each line,builds a URL string and hits URL.To make the process faster I have used thread concept.

```
//snippet in processFile method
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split("\t");

    if (//some condition) {
        String url = //build url from the current line  
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass(url));
        t.start();
    } 
}

public MyClass(String strUrl) {
    this.strUrl = strUrl;
}

public void run() {
    urlHit(strUrl);//call function to hit current URL
}
```

Now my concern is `sendSMS` method should get called only after all URLs got hit.

I tried using `join` method which works fine but it is as good as not using threads.

Comment: Using `async` is easier for multitreaded code.

Comment: So you can use `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: You have a problem with calling `join()`, yet you do not show how you call it. Please rectify this.

Comment: @arkadiy refer above code:Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass(url));
        t.start();t.join();

Comment: The code in the question shows `start()` but not `join()`. Please edit. More substantially, `start()` followed by `join()` before another `start()` causes all threads to run sequentially. No parallelization happens..

Comment: Please read full question @Arkadiy ,I wrote the same reason why I am avoiding join method.Same is the reason for not keeping join method in my question code

Comment: Your problem comes from the way you use join method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply synchronisation, and there are various ways of applying synchronisation in java. You can use `wait()` and `notify()` where the sendSms waits until a notification is recieved that the urls have been hit.
Check the examples [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/) to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) API.

Refer to this post on usage of `invokeALl()`

[How to use invokeAll() to let all thread pool do their task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202388/how-to-use-invokeall-to-let-all-thread-pool-do-their-task/39547616#39547616)

Replace your

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass(url));
```

with

`Callable` task and submit your `Callable` tasks to `ExecutorService`.

Once you are done with processing of all URLs by following of one of available options, invoke `sendSMS()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using an executor in this case is a good idea to limit the number of threads being executed concurrently. Your steps to achieve what you are after are as follows:

- Construct a list of *Callable*, each would create the URL and hit the constructed URL.
- Create a Thread pool executor and call *invokeAll* with list of *Callable* objects as parameter.
- Once invokeAll returns, you can loop on the returned list of *Callable* and call *get()* to get your result if needed, for instance to confirm that the URL was hit successfully.

For instance, the following would look like the code you use to create the *Callable* list:

```
List<Callable> createUrlAndHit = new ArrayList<Callable>();
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split("\t");

    if (//some condition) {
        createUrlAndHit.add(new Callable(){
           //Add your logic here...., or create a specific implementation of callable to instantiate with your url
        });
    } 
}
```

The next step would be to invokeAll:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...);
List<Future<Callable>> futures = executor.invokeAll(createUrlAndHit);
//Loop on results and send SMS
for(Callable c : futures){
  //send sms..
}
```